# HTTPS proxy like Charles

Tags: node.js, https, proxy, charles-proxy

I want to implement proxy server in node.js which is somewhat similar to Charles proxy - it should intercept HTTPS requests from my mobile app, decipher them, route some of them depending on body content to original backend and mock others with some static files.

1. How this HTTPS stuff is handled in Charles or other proxies?
2. Will I need self-signed root certificateon mobile device?
3. Are there any libraries which will help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1. How this HTTPS stuff is handled in Charles or other proxies?

Technically, Charles Proxy or [Proxyman.io](https://proxyman.io/) (the one I'm using now) would do the following steps:

- Generate a root certificate and install to keychain and trust it. This steps would do once.
- Open the Local Server (at 8888 or 9090).
- Override the HTTP Proxy in System to this port. Thus, all traffic will go through the port. You could use the `networksetup` CLI to easily achieve or Privileged Helper tool on macOS for high performance and secure.
- As soon as capture the first socket: If It's a HTTP request, get a first line message. Ex:

```
GET https://api.producthunt.com/v1/posts HTTP/1.1
```

- Then open the forward socket to this URL.
- If it's a HTTPS, make sure do SSL-Handshake and then get the first line message.
- Finally, just get the rest of message and parse to proper message([HTTPCParser](https://github.com/nodejs/http-parser) from NodeJS would be potential candidate)
- Send data forward and back from the client and the destination server.
- Do manipulation actions if you need since you're the true mitm.

> 2. Will I need self-signed root certification mobile device?

Yes, you must install the Root Certificate in the first steps to your iOS device. For the Header/Response detail. Check chls.pro/ssl or proxy.man/ssl from those Charles or Proxyman, and see the content.

You can do it on iOS Simulator by using [ADVTrustStore](https://github.com/ADVTOOLS/ADVTrustStore)

> 3. Are there any libraries which will help me?

You can check the those famous open source to see how it works
- [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/) 
- [zapproxy](https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy)
- [http toolkit](https://github.com/httptoolkit)

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Do I need to override HTTP Proxy if I'm not going to intercept requests from local system, only from iOS device?

Comment: You don't need to override HTTP Proxy in mac if you would only capture the traffics from iOS device. However, make sure you open proper port in mac (ex: 9090), and config the Wifi Proxy in your iPhone to this port and IP.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How this HTTPS stuff is handled in Charles or other proxies?

[@gaku answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58526789/11565176) does a good job explaining everything that is required to do for intercepting the [`CONNECT` requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection).

If you also want to read and manipulate an https traffic, the request needs to be signed by a Certificate that your proxy can decrypt.

For this, the requests that your client sends should be encrypted using the proxy's self-signed certificate.

So if, for example, the client making the request is a mobile phone and you have your proxy running on your laptop. (with the certificate added to your laptop's key chain)

You first set the proxy settings on your mobile, to send traffic to your laptop
And then add the self-signed certificate to your mobile's key chain. (this steps vary across Android and iOS)

> 2. Will I need a self-signed root certificate on a mobile device?

As mentioned, yes you will need a self-signed root certificate that needs to be used both by the proxy server (to decrypt the request) and the client (browser/mobile/OS) to encrypt the request.

Most proxying tools, Charles, Proxyman or Requestly (*the one that I use*), issue their own certificates, which is quite easy to do with tools like [openssl](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities) to generate [X.509](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) certificates.

It's not that hard to write a simple wrapper for these in NodeJS (or use any of the ones that already exist on npm)

> 3. Are there any libraries which will help me?

I would recommend you do that too

> Every proxy takes many biased decisions to meet its requirements. This is because the web, although standardized, has many undocumented edge cases that a proxy has to take care of.
> So most good proxies that I know of, develop their own solution from the ground up, using only the native modules that the programming language provides.

In case you want to reference a few code examples of node-based implementations, you can take a look at these open-source proxies mostly built with native libraries

1. [node-http-mitm-proxy](https://github.com/joeferner/node-http-mitm-proxy) : A simple and easily extensible proxy, that does a good job to cover most of the edge cases. This does not implement generating your own certificates.
2. [requestly-proxy](https://github.com/requestly/requestly-proxy) : A powerful proxy that provides handlers to modify any part of the HTTP request lifecycle. This is what runs inside the [Requestly desktop app](https://github.com/requestly/requestly-desktop-app)
3. [mockhttp](https://github.com/httptoolkit/mockttp) : Another powerful proxy written in node that also supports HTTP2 and modifying websockets. The proxy is built by the awesome [Tim Perry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/68051/tim-perry) and is the core of [HTTPToolkit](https://github.com/httptoolkit)